# Level 12 isOver

Tags: vim-adventures

Need some help here:

[image]

How to replace the word `bored` with the context of the buffer? I can't `diw` because then I won't have place to stand on. I can `ciw` but then I can't paste directly from the buffer without typing a letter first.

Answer (score 2):

Okay it was easy after finding `.` - it repeats the whole replace part

Comment: where is the '.' key?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Vim Adventures, but using regular Vim you'd use `"_` to select the "black hole register" so the text you replace goes nowhere, then `cw` to change word, then once you're in insert mode, hit `ctrl r` to select a register, then `"` to paste the contents of the default unnamed register.

If your contents are in a different register, substitute that register with the final `"`. For example, if your desired contents are in the clipboard register (`*`) then when in insert mode, type `ctrl r` then `*`.

tl;dr - `"_cw^R"`

Comment: Problem is there is no `Ctrl-R` in Vim Adventures.